# Sorting array of structure for with two structure variable?

Tags: c, structure

I am having trouble sorting the following array.

How do I sort the `temp_var[]` array based on `temp_var[].trade_date` and `temp_var[].trans_amount`  ?

```
typedef struct      
{
    char    trans_d                  [2],      
            trans_amount            [10], 
            trans_me                 [8],
            account                 [10], 
            trans                  [16],
            trade_date              [12],
            setnt_date              [12];
} what_if;

what_if  temp_var[100];

void swap(what_if *a, what_if *b)
{
    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}


void bubbleSort(what_if a[], int size)
{
    for (i=0; i<size-1; i++)
    {
        for (j=size-1; j>i; j--)  
            if (strcmp(a[j].trade_date , a[j-1].trade_date) < 0 )
                swap(&a[j], &a[j-1]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //after read the structure values
    bubbleSort(temp_var,t_count);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code you gave not compile or have runtime errors?

Comment: Is this a homework? If so, you should indicate it.

Comment: hi puddingfox, it got sorting for on trade_date , is there is any mistake u felt there.(date like 20100608)

Comment: there i sort base on single structure variable, now i need to to with two structure variable.

Answer (score 0):

You simply check the 2nd sorting criteria if the 1st is equal. Please check wether the trans_amount field can be compared this way. The code could be shorter, my intention was to demonstrate how this works.

```
int first = strcmp(a[j].trade_date , a[j-1].trade_date);
 if ( first == 0 ) {
     if ( strcmp(a[j].trans_amount , a[j-1].trans_amount) < 0 )
         swap(&a[j], &a[j-1]);
 }
 else if ( first < 0 ) {
    swap(&a[j], &a[j-1]);
 }
```